# Doble selector con función jquery

Tags: jquery

He hecho un menu que desaparece y aparece según mueves el raton por según que zona de la web y que cuando estas sobre el pasa a ser opaco, pero le he puesto un desplegable dentro y al seleccionarlo me cambia la opacidad como si no estuviera sobre el. Tengo la sensación que el fallo lo tengo en el doble selector de jquery. lo he hecho asi:

```
$("#Menu_"+menu+',#MenuOpcion_'+menu).hover(function(){ clearTimeout(thread); $("#Menu_"+menu).css("opacity", "1"); }, function(){ $("#Menu_"+menu).css("opacity", ""); });
```

MenuOpcion+menu es el id que tiene el select, pero no me va. ¿es posible que el doble selector no se haga asi?

el código completo del menu es este:

```
function Menuopciones(pagina,menu) {
timeout = 800;
var thread; 
$("#"+pagina).mousemove(function(){ 
    $("#Menu_"+menu).removeClass('oculto').addClass('bounceIn');
    $('#MenuOpcion_'+menu).select2('close');
    clearTimeout(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(mousestopped, timeout);
});
$("#Menu_"+menu+',#MenuOpcion_'+menu).hover(function(){ clearTimeout(thread); $("#Menu_"+menu).css("opacity", "1"); }, function(){ $("#Menu_"+menu).css("opacity", ""); });
function mousestopped(){ $("#Menu_"+menu).removeClass('bounceIn').addClass('oculto'); };
$("#Menu_"+menu).draggable();
}
```

¿que puede ser que tenga mal para que al estar sobre el select me cambie la opacidad del menu?

Comment: Publicá el código `HTML` y si podes subí un ejemplo a jsfiddle o similar.

Comment: Si tienes dudas de si el selector doble no funciona, separalos crea una función que sería la que toma el comportamiento del hover que no es más que lo que ya tienes dentro del cuerpo del function y luego le asignas esa misma función a ambos selectores individualmente